# Replace blog with static page redirect rest to /blog with htaaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that currently has a WordPress blog. I want to move the blog into `/blog` and make the static page the new "root".

That's easy in terms of FTP, just moving folders along.

However, I'd love to get anything that would normally be 404 to get redirected to the `/blog` part so content doesn't get lost on the migration.

Is this doable with `.hatccess`?

Current `.htaccess` file:

```
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Indexes
Options All -Indexes

# REDIRECT https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Dynamically generated by WP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN FileETag MTime Size
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
# END FileETag MTime Size<!--formatted-->

# Protecting htaccess
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# Protecting wpconfig.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>%
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the `.htaccess` file that you are presumably moving into the `/blog` subdirectory. Do you also have a `.htaccess` file in the document root? Presumably you want `/blog` to now be part of the URL? Have you updated the WordPress side of things - or do you also need assistance with this?

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite . I've added the file Moving WordPress is simple on my end and yeah, I just want blog to be the old homepage and for posts to work.

Comment: What was the format of your URLs before moving to the `/blog` subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "current `.htaccess` file" you have posted is the `.htaccess` file you intend to move to `/blog/.htaccess`. In which case you will need to change it as follows:

```
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Indexes
Options All -Indexes

# REDIRECT https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# Dynamically generated by WP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN FileETag MTime Size
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
# END FileETag MTime Size<!--formatted-->

# Protecting htaccess
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# Protecting wpconfig.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Notable changes:

- Changed HTTP to HTTPS redirect to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of a backreference. With it being in a subdirectory (`blog`), the subdirectory would otherwise be omited from the redirect to HTTPS.
- Commented out (removed) the `RewriteBase` directive. This is not required here, but if you did need to set this, it should be set to `RewriteBase /blog`.
- Removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. ie. Changed this `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` to this `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

  Without the `RewriteBase` defined, this is now relative to the current directory, ie. `/blog`. Without having to explicitly state the `/blog` directory.
- You had an erroneous `%` at the end of the file?

> I'd love to get anything that would normally be 404 to get redirected to the `/blog` part so content doesn't get lost on the migration.

This can perhaps be refined if we know the format of your original URLs, however, we basically need to redirect any request for anywhere outside of the `/blog` subdirectory - that would trigger a 404 - to be redirected to the `/blog` subdirectory.

You need to create a new `.htaccess` file in the document root with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any 404s back to the "/blog" directory
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^blog/ /blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above would redirect a request for `/foo` to `/blog/foo`. But a request for `/blog/bar` would not be touched by this directive and routed through WordPress as normal (probably resulting in a 404 generated by WordPress).

You should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is so helpful @MrWhite!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ErrorDocument directive

`ErrorDocument 404 /blog`